# How to kill a process (query) in ClickHouse

Tags: clickhouse

Is there any way to kill an idle query in ClickHouse? I have an OPTIMIZE query that will never be completed (as it is running against a ReplicatedMergeTree table) blocking a table that I need to delete.

Answer (score 12):

I usually run

```sql
SELECT query_id, query FROM system.processes;
```

To find running queries. From that list I find `query_id` of query I want to kill and then execute

```sql
KILL QUERY WHERE query_id = '<id>';
```

More info can be found in [Documentation on KILL QUERY](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/query_language/misc/#kill-query)

To kill Mutation, there's similar [`KILL MUTATION`](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/query_language/misc/#kill-mutation).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is a [replace_running_query](https://clickhouse.yandex/reference_en.html#replace_running_query) option.

In short, you can add a `query_id` parameter to your HTTP request, like that:

`http://localhost:8123/?query=SELECT * FROM system.numbers LIMIT 100000000& replace_running_query=1&query_id=example`

Then do a second HTTP request, with the same `query_id`:

`http://localhost:8123/?query=SELECT 1&replace_running_query=1&query_id=example`

The server will cancel the first query and run the second one instead.

You can override the option (it is disabled by default) in your config file to get rid of placing it in the request arguments.

Comment: I am not using the HTTP interface but the clickhouse-client I don't think is possible to use the `replace_running_query` trough the client. Btw I am not the system administrator so I could not modify the configuration or open the 8123 port. I asked system administrators to restart the node that was affected and that just solved the issue (but was not ideal).

Comment: @DamnWidget by the way, I made [clickhouse-cli](https://github.com/hatarist/clickhouse-cli) which kills query with the same method (using replace_running_query) on Ctrl+C. And hey, thanks for Anaconda, I use it a lot!

Comment: Gonna give it a try thanks!. I also use anaconda a lot that is the main reason that I wrote it :)